# How should we include the purpose verb in a german sentence?

Tags: grammar, verb

If, for instance, I want to say something like... ''I would like something to QUENCH my thirst with'', can I put it like this in German?

Ich möchte etwas zum meinen Durst löchern.

Further illustration regarding likewise constituent sequences is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The thing you are looking for is an infinitive construction; both in German and in English. Why did a grammar book not help? I vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ich möchte etwas, um meinen Durst zu löschen."

(durch-) "löchern" means to make (many) holes.

The general sentence structure in these cases is "Ich möchte / brauche / will etwas, um etwas anderes zu tun". The first part is about what you want, then you use ", um `goal` zu `verb infinitive`".